# kint() my_theme_preprocess_node error

Tags: 8, acquia-dev-desktop

After using the function `kint()` (in the submodule **Devel Kint** that is part of [**Devel**](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)) in my *mytheme*.theme file to output the variables :

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  kint($variables);
}
```

I get the following error:

> RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "C:\Drupal\modules\contrib\devel\kint\kint\Kint.class.php" at line 263. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 141 of vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage.php).

My environment is as follows: Drupal 8.7.1, Devel modules:

```
 devel                       Devel                       Development         8.x-2.1 8002           Installed   no core
 devel_generate              Devel Generate              Development         8.x-2.1                Uninstalled no core
 kint                        Devel Kint                  Development         8.x-2.1 8000           Installed   no core
```

If anyone should know the cause of this (if it is down to the **Devel** module then where should I ask the question as the editor suggested that this forum is not the right place to ask about Drupal modules) - please help!

Comment: I've gotten this error many times, I think that it is because that kint is sending some headers that causes the page load to break. The error is only temporary and should disappear, when you remove the `kint()` call.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! When you state facts and ask a question like _Any suggestions?_ you are asking a too broad question. We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access. If then the PHP error is merely caused from Kint, this is not even a Drupal-related question, as [Kint](https://github.com/kint-php/kint) is a generic PHP tool, not a Drupal tool.

Comment: Is it the same when you call `ksm($variables)`?

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, ksm($variables) works fine. Can I upvote your answer somehow?

Comment: I always get this with `kint()`. `ksm()`works. I think it is a bug in **Devel** and should be posted as such to the project's [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/devel).